# FluentMigrator create index with custom operator

Tags: fluent-migrator

Can I express following PostgreSQL statement using Fluent Migrator:

```
CREATE INDEX index1 ON table1(column1 text_pattern_ops)
```

Can't seem to have a proper methods?

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight forward way to do it using the Fluent interface. You could probably do it by executing direct native sql via the Execute function.